# .dcproj showing in OSX finder as folder instead of project file

Tags: xcode, macos, svn, widget

I downloaded a .dcproj file from github for a widget (https://github.com/donatj/Hidden-File-Toggle-Widget), except github has turned it into folders because, to my limited understanding, that's all the .dcproj file is, a directory structure. (I may be wrong, as I don't use .dcproj in my day to day travels)

How can I turn it back into something usable, so that I can create a widget from the source code?

***EDIT:***

I seem to have found the problem. It appears Dashcode does not automatically install with Xcode. I'm currently downloading it now. I'll update if installing dashcode fixes the problem.

Comment: Sorry, what's wrong with the answer I posted below? Let me know what needs to be changed here, and I'll happily change it :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Dashcode installed to open a .dcproj file. It doesn't come with Xcode.